# Eclipse: Cannot find project in Project Explorer

Tags: eclipse

I am using Eclipse Juno SR1 Java EE, and checked out code from SVN as an Eclipse project.  I am able to click on files in the project to verify everything was ok. The next time I rebooted, I can't see the project in the Project Explorer window.

A few things I checked: The menu item Project > Open Project is greyed out, indicating there are no closed projects. The project's file tree exists in my workspace. Eclipse won't let me create a new project with the same name because one already exists.

This is my first time using Juno, is there some new control that hides projects from view?

Comment: Yes, you can hide projects in views. Try the dropdown menu (down triangle) to create, select or deselect "working sets".

Answer (score 3):

"File -> Import -> General -> Existing Projects Into Workspace"

"File -> Import -> Android -> Existing Android Code Into Workspace" doesn't do what you're trying to accomplish (been there...).

Assuming the above lines mean what they say, the first tells Eclipse to recognize what you're importing as an official Project. The 2nd tells Eclipse that you're importing only the code, not the Project itself.

Comment: Don't forget to uncheck "Copy content into workspace" in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it's just because .project file is missing. If you have any other project, copy its .project file and paste inside the main folder of the project you're trying to import.

Answer (score 0):

Try starting with the clean option in command line, maybe that should fix it

eclipse -clean

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but unfortunately that didn't work.  I'll wait awhile to see if anyone has other suggestions, and if not, I think I'll have to delete my workspace and start from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

try 
file -> switch workspace -> other

and tell eclipse where your workspace is

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem with RAD. What I did was:
imported only those projects which were deployed locally in my portal server.
Did a clean build.
Started the server.

It worked for me. Able to access my application. Rest of the projects which were not deployed as part of my local portal server, I will import them on need basis later.